# How to take multiple lists and nest them?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested-lists

Currently working with a text file that is read into python and then must be made into lists with a list (nested I guess?) So far I've tried double splitting the file but to no avail. This is what the reader code looks like:

```
def populationreader():
    with open("PopulationofAnnecy", "r") as in_file:
        for lines in in_file:
            Nested = lines.split(',')
            print Nested
```

And from this I get the result:

```
['State', ' Total #', '% passed', '%female\n']
['Alabama', '126', '79', '17\n']
['Alaska', '21', '100', '10\n']
['Arizona', '190', '59', '16\n']
['Arkansas', '172', '49', '28\n']
etc...
```

How would I go about removing the first line, getting rid of \n and also nesting the lists so they look more like this:

```
[[“Alabama”, 126, 79, 17], [“Alaska”, 21, 100, 10] …. ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to declare the list in which you want to store the elements:

```
result = []
```

then, since `lines.split(',')` will return a list of *strings*, you will have to convert them into integers. To do this, you can assign the elements of the list to separate variables:

```
a,b,c,d = lines.split(',')
```

then convert the ones you want, and append them to `result` as a list:

```
result.append([a, int(b), int(c), int(d)])
```

Answer (score 1):

before spliting it `strip` it

```
def populationreader():
    with open("PopulationofAnnecy", "r") as in_file:
        for lines in in_file:
            Nested = lines.strip().split(',')

            print Nested
```

to make integers  you can use

```
[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in nested]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to create the nested list:

```
def populationreader():
    with open("PopulationofAnnecy", "r") as in_file:
        nested = [line.strip().split(',') for line in in_file][1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove `\n` using strip

2.use append to add individual lines to result list; start at index 1 to skip first line.

```
    def populationreader():
        Nested = []
        with open("PopulationofAnnecy", "r") as in_file:
            for lines in in_file[1:]:
                Nested.append(lines.split(',').strip())
        print Nested
```